# How to configure DispatcherServlet in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot

In a traditional Spring Web app, it's possible to override `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.createDispatcherServlet`, call `super.createDispatcherServlet` and then set the following init parameters on the returned instance?

```
setThreadContextInheritable
setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound
```

How do I achieve this in a Spring Boot app?

Comment: Try adding a @Bean of type DispatcherServlet and setting whatever properties you need directly.

Comment: @Shaheer Doing that will require me to fully configure the `DispatcherServlet` myself. As I stated in my question, the traditional method uses the `super.createDispatcherServlet` call to let the superclass do the heavy-lifting. That should be a better way other than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The last one is simply a property in your `application.properties` `spring.mvc.throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound=true` (default is `false` btw!).  For the other one it is probably the easiest to create a `BeanPostProcessor` for that, as you either configure the `DispatcherServlet` by hand or use the properties. On the other hand you only need a `DispatcherServlet` and Spring Boot will still take care of everything else.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'll reply back as soon as I've tried the `BeanPostProcessor` method.

Comment: using a BeanPostProcessor worked like a charm for me, thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

You can define your own configuration and achieve this, as shown below:

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig {

@Bean
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
    dispatcherServlet.setThreadContextInheritable(true);
    dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    return dispatcherServlet;
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {

    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet());
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(0);
    registration.setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);

    return registration;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you read my comment, 2nd from the top on the original post?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone trying to solve this issue, we solved it this way :

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig {

  @Autowired
  RequestContextFilter filter;

  @Autowired
  DispatcherServlet servlet;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    // Normal mode
    filter.setThreadContextInheritable(true);

    // Debug mode
    servlet.setThreadContextInheritable(true);

    servlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
  }
}
```

For some reason, when running our spring boot application NOT in debug mode, Spring's `RequestContextFilter` overrode `DispatcherServlet` `ThreadContextInheritable` property. In debug mode setting the servlet is enough.

Comment: If you’re saying this what you showed only works in debug mode, that obviously isn’t a solution. The debug mode is for debugging, and no one runs their application in debug mode in Prod

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar That is not what I was trying to say, obviously I would not post it if it was not production ready. 
What I meant is that for some reason, Spring boot autoconfigures the application differently in debug mode. In debug mode `DispatcherServlet` bean takes priority over `RequestContextFilter`, so setting the servlet's property is enough to make debug mode work. Launching the application in "production mode" the priority is the other way round. What we do in the code is setting both of them so that it can work no matter the mode the application is running in.

Comment: this sounds like a bug, you should report it on their GitHub.